# programmatically click on column in Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a simple drilldown chart: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/7xEhW/)

Depending on the selected values in a table I need to dynamically click on specific column in this chart. How can I do that? I found how to click on the legend area, but not on column.

I tried to simply trigger a click event on the specific column, but in this way it not works:

```
$('rect:not(:first):nth-child(1):first').click()
```

I assume sth must be hidden in the charts api, but I can't see where it is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cna use built-in function for firing events: `firePointEvent(type)`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/7xEhW/31/

For first column it is: `chart.series[0].data[0].firePointEvent('click');`

FirePointEvent is not part of docs, but it's used internally.

Comment: Thank you! You've saved a lot of working hours for me.

Comment: What is the equivalent for android ?

Comment: It's the same. It's not part of the official API, so you can't use it from Android wrapper, only using JS code